# Updating user-level

Tags: php, logging

I am trying to update User-level by a simple form but it showing me undefined index and not updating the level wil anybody help me to do this?

```
<h3>Update User Level</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
UserID:<br/>
<input type="text" name="upduser" maxlength="30"> <br/>
Designation code:<br>
<?php
//require 'config.php';
$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select`user_dsgntn_code` from `hr_user`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $options .="<option>" . $row['user_dsgntn_code'] . "</option>";
}
            $dropdown="<form id='designation' name='designation' method='POST' action=''>
                <select name='updlevel' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
                  " . $options . "
                </select>
            </form>";
        echo $dropdown;
        //do_alert("$options");
        ?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update Level">
</form>
<?
//require 'config.php';

if ( isset( $_POST['upduser'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['upduser'] )&&
isset ($_POST['updlevel']));
{
$updtuser=$_POST['upduser'];
$updtlevel=$_POST['updlevel'];
$sql_upd="update `hr_user` set user_dsgntn_code='$updtlevel' WHERE user_id='$updtuser'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_upd) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: You have two forms, only one of them gets submitted when you click the submit button. Combine them into one form.

Comment: @Barmar How I can combine them?

Comment: Get rid of the extra `<form>` element. Forms also can't be nested inside each other like this.

Comment: @Barmar please will you show me your action in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra form around the `<select>`.

```
<h3>Update User Level</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
UserID:<br/>
<input type="text" name="upduser" maxlength="30"> <br/>
Designation code:<br>
<?php
//require 'config.php';
$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select`user_dsgntn_code` from `hr_user`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $options .="<option>" . $row['user_dsgntn_code'] . "</option>";
}
            $dropdown="<select id='designation' name='updlevel' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
                  " . $options . "
                </select>";
        echo $dropdown;
        //do_alert("$options");
        ?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update Level">
</form>
```

Comment: Undefined index: upduser
Undefined index: updlevel

Comment: You have an extra `;` at the end of `if (isset()...);` statement.